# How can we use already existing facebook pages as pages for objects of facebook open graph application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

I want to create facebook open graph application with build in object type and custom action type. For objects, I don't want to create a page for each object and want to use already existing facebook fan pages (pages used by facebook while adding likes). 
Like if my object is of book type, I don't want to create page for each of the books rather I wan to use already existing pages representing books(pages that show up while adding likes for books or pages that are shown for likes for books).
And I want to use custom action on these objects.

How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the URL for the book pages they should work as "profile" objects in the graph. Soon they will be "book" objects, but in the meantime you can use them as profiles.

Comment: @Pual "Soon they will be book objects" means what? If these are profile objects will I be able to perform custom actions or other built in actions like read, watch etc. on them?

Comment: You can't `read` a `profile` but when they become books you can.